# Android Unit test for XML parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, unit-testing

I am attempting to write a unit test for parsing an XML document in my Android app in Android Studio. I using the same approach I used 2 years ago and I'm wondering if things have changed with the ties. In my approach, I create a Java library where the parser class and test will live. I have to convince Android Studio to copy the test input XML document to a place where the test class can find it at runtime using some Gradle logic:

```
testClasses.doFirst {
    ant.copy(todir: sourceSets['test'].output.classesDir) {
        fileset(dir:sourceSets['test'].output.resourcesDir)
    }
}
```

I load the XML at runtime using a Java 1.2 technique

```
this.problems = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("input.xml");
```

The xml is then found and fed into my parser which needs the XML pull API. I set a dependency on the KXML pull API in the Java library Gradle build but then I need to do a work around to avoid the API being redundantly compiled in since Gradle doesn't yet [support a "provided" scope](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-784). The whole process is a mess that I'd rather avoid.

Now I know A/S now supports POJO unit tests within the main Android module but even that feels awkward and I don't know if it scratches my itch. What I want to know is wether there is a better way to go about this? How does one test a basic XML parse in the most simplest way?

Comment: I read your question quickly, but what about just defining a new gradle module/project and write your unit tests there in the test source set? The xml file could be in the test resources.

Comment: That's exactly what I outline in my current approach. This suffers from all the above described work-arounds. A/S does not include the test resources in the classpath without modifying the build.gradle. The pull parser becomes a redundant dependency when the module is included in the overall application.

Comment: What I want is to quickly write a test that says this POJO with the given XML file should produce that object model. I don't want to use the default Android Unit Test framework that runs on device, I don't want to mess with build flavors to inline POJO tests in the main module, but I don't like having to dance around the KXML dependency in a Java lib or the resource copy bug.

Comment: any recent improvements, changes or better ideas on testing xml generation on Android?